# I'd like to make my plus and minus button change that sub total and total price, but the price didn't change, anyone can solved my problems?

Tags: html, jquery, laravel, subtotal

here is my code, i've tried to cummulative the price with quantity per product but still stuck, anyone can solved my problems? i need your help guys, thanks for tryin' my code

```
<td>
    {{-- <input type="number" value="2" class="form-control input-kuantitas"> --}}
    <div class="wrapper">
        <span class="minus">-</span>
        <span class="num" id="quantity_{{ $pesanan->id }}">1</span>
        <span class="plus">+</span>
    </div>
</td>
    
<td id="price_{{ $pesanan->id }}">{{ $pesanan->harga }}</td>
```

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 ms-auto">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Total</th>
                    <td id="total">Rp. {{ $harga }}</td>
                </tr>
```

```
<script>
        $('.plus').click(function (e) { 
            const elem=$(this).prev();
            let qty = parseInt(elem.html())+1;
            elem.html(qty);
        });
        $('.minus').click(function (e) { 
            const elem=$(this).next();
            let qty = parseInt(elem.html());
            if(qty>1){
                qty--;
            }
            elem.html(qty);
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: In the code provided you aren't editing the total or sub total at all. You are just editing the shown qty.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult assume how the 'total' is calculate since you're not given in the above scenario.

Try this one.

```
<script>

    $('.plus').click(function (e) { 
        const elem=$(this).prev();
        const getId=elem.attr("id").split("_")[1]; // To find the price id
        const price=parseFloat($("#price_"+getId).text()); // price amount
        let qty = parseInt(elem.html())+1;
        elem.html(qty);
        $("#total").html("Rp. "+price*qty); // set total, assume total is qty * price
    });
    $('.minus').click(function (e) { 
        const elem=$(this).next();
        const getId=elem.attr("id").split("_")[1]; // To find the price id
        const price=parseFloat($("#price_"+getId).text()); // price amount
        let qty = parseInt(elem.html());
        if(qty>1){
            qty--;
        }
        elem.html(qty);
        $("#total").html("Rp. "+price*qty); // set total, assume total is qty * price
    });
</script>
```

Hope this code will help you.